# Show analyticity of $\frac{1-e^{-x^2}}{x^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

function $f$ is given by   $f(x)=\frac{1-e^{-x^2}}{x^2}$ if $x\neq0$,  $f(x)=1$ if $x=0$
I want to show analycity of the function. on R
I'm trying to apply Taylor's theorem    and show remainder term of ordern n of the taylor expansion goes to zero.
Consider n-th order remainder term $R_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(c)(x-x_0)}{n!}$ for some $c$ in $(x,x_0)$
Then we have $|R_n|\le\frac{M_nr^n}{n!} $ for $|x-x_0|<r $
$M_n=sup\{f^{(n)}(x) |x  \in (x_0-r,x_0+r)\}$
If $M_n$ is bounded for every $x_0 \in R$ and $r>0$ then analyticity of f on whole R follows.
I'm stuck at this point.
How can I show boundedness of $M_n$?
Should I use chan rule higher order?  or is my approach flawed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that $e^{-x^2}$ is analytic and can be written
$$e^{-x^2} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-x^2)^k}{k!} = 1 - x^2 + \frac12 x^4 + \cdots$$
for all $x \in \mathbb R.$

Then
$$1 - e^{-x^2} = - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-x^2)^k}{k!} = x^2 - \frac12 x^4 + \cdots$$
and
$$\frac{1 - e^{-x^2}}{x^2} = - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-x^2)^{k-1}}{k!} = 1 - \frac12 x^2 + \cdots$$

Thus $\frac{1 - e^{-x^2}}{x^2}$ is analytic.